# RCLCPP logging macros not a single expression

Tags: ros, ros2, rclcpp, ros-crystal, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just discovered after a lot of confusion that the `RCLCPP_` logging macros do not expand to a single expression and therefore cannot be used in brace-less `if` clauses and `for` loops. For example, this doesn't compile for me because the compiler sees an unexpected `else`:

```
if (true)
  RCLCPP_INFO(node->get_logger(), "true");
else
  RCLCPP_INFO(node->get_logger(), "false");
```

Is this expected?

Edit: added the mistakenly elided semi-colons from the original question

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/319004/rclcpp-logging-macros-not-a-single-expression/) by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on ROS Answers with karma: 971 on 2019-03-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-03-20**:
"Expected" I don't know, but yes, all `RCLCPP_*` macros are two-liners: see [here](https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/43f891dac8ff27839079f1c8b39527972ce65fc6/rclcpp/resource/logging.hpp.em#L92-L97).

Might be an oversight: perhaps they should be wrapped in `do {  } while(0);` constructs?

**Comment by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) on 2019-03-20**:
There was some discussion about this last fall [here](https://github.com/ros2/rcutils/issues/113). I suspect that `;`'s might help you in the above example, but, otherwise, ROS 2 linters require curly braces on all if statements, so it's understandable as to how this was not caught earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@gvdhoorn is correct, it's an oversight that you cannot do:

```
if (condition)
  RCLCPP_INFO(...);
else
  RCLCPP_INFO(...);
```

The macro's contents should be wrapped within a `do { ... } while(0)`. This is done in the equivalent C API's, see:

https://github.com/ros2/rcutils/blob/9e1f5593763cfdc64f2e590dbafb0c316926f628/resource/logging_macros.h.em#L66-L75

But the `rclcpp` one's do not do this:

https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/blob/43f891dac8ff27839079f1c8b39527972ce65fc6/rclcpp/resource/logging.hpp.em#L92-L104

I'd recommend opening an issue on `rclcpp` and ideally providing a pull request to help us fix it :D

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2019-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jdlangs](https://answers.ros.org/users/2128/jdlangs/) on 2019-03-21**:
Thanks, I was really confused that no one seemed to be bothered that function-call semantics had been broken, knowing that many more people would be falling into this non-obvious trap. I will be able to open a PR against rclcpp shortly.

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-04-03**:
See https://github.com/ros2/rclcpp/pull/681